# How to cast a custom type that is a pointer to slice

Tags: go

I have a library with the following custom type and function:

```
package mylib

type SystemInstances []SystemInstance

func (c *Client) SystemInstances() (*SystemInstances, error) {
<SNIP>
}
```

Then in my consumer code I call this function.

```
    instances, err := cluster.Client.SystemInstances()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
```

So at this point instances is a *SystemInstances.

I have the following struct (reduced for brevity)

```
type Cluster struct {
    // I WANT A SINGLE SYSTEM INSTANCE HERE, since there will always be exactly one despite the api returning a list
    System *mylib.SystemInstance
}
```

How on earth do I cast this? I've tried everything. Usually my editor (intelliJ) is smart enough to figure this out but not in this case.

```
    cluster := &Cluster

    cluster.System = instances[0] // how do I cast this here? obviously this doesn't work
```

Comment: There is no "casting" in Go, and I don't think you need to convert anything either. `cluster.System` needs a pointer, but you're passing a value. Also make sure you really want to return a `*SystemInstances`, which uses an unnecessary pointer to a slice.

Answer (score 2):

It is a pointer to a slice. First get the slice, and then you can index it. So this should work:

```
 cluster.System = &(*instances)[0]
```

Comment: Yea that doesn't work.

Comment: cluster.go:72:19: cannot use (*instances)[0] (variable of type "mylib".SystemInstance) as *"mylib".SystemInstance value in assignment

Comment: It wants a pointer. See the edited answer